# Error inserting date values into database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am having a weird problem inserting a date value into my database. When debugging my program, i realized it inserts the first five rows into the database but on the sixth it throws an exception. I verified if it was a syntax error or if something changed along the way by checking the first 5 queries that could execute successfully with the sixth and they are both the same. If there is a problem with the type, it should throw the exception from the beginning. What do you think?

This is the error I get

> *The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.*

Comment: can you post your code if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

That suggests you're specifying the value as a string, and performing a conversion. Don't do that. Avoid string conversions wherever you possibly can. (I suspect there's quite possibly a disconnect between the string format you're providing and the one that's being used for parsing. Removing the string conversion completely is the best fix for this.)

Instead, provide the value as a `SqlParameter` with a `DateTime` value.

Comment: Yes i did something like that so i can specify in what format i want the date in `string affectation_date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");`. I'll try what you suggested, but how come it inserts a couple of rows before throwing the exception?

Comment: @Malyk: But the value in the database *shouldn't be a string to start with*. Get rid of the string conversions and you don't need to think about what format is used - it's a non-issue. Have a look at the rows that were inserted successfully and the one that wasn't - my *guess* is that you'll find the ones which were inserted successfully had a day-of-month of 12 or less. Oh, and using `hh` would lose data anyway - that's a 12-hour clock. This is precisely the sort of reason you shouldn't be doing string conversions.

Comment: You are right about the day-of-month being less than 12. I'll be using `SqlParameter` then. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes because of the difference between DateTime type in C# which start at 01-01-0001 and in SQL Server which is `January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999', [check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), so I think (due to the error Jon explained) you are trying to insert a Date value which is less than 01-01-1753 into SQL Server. That's why the SQL Exception is shown.